# skobbler (skmaps ) annotation with buttons

Tags: android, button, annotations, skmaps

I want to add an annotation on an skmap, like so:
SKAnnotation annotation1 = new SKAnnotation(p1.id);

The annotation must contain 2 buttons with the respective handlers.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try that by adding an annotation with a view and in that view you can add your custom button. 
Here's the code from the demo project for doing that:

```
SKAnnotation annotationFromView = new SKAnnotation(15);
annotationFromView.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.423573, 37.761349));
annotationFromView.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
customView =
        (RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater)
getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.layout_custom_view, null, false);

//If width and height of the view  are not power of 2 the actual size of the
//image will be the next power of 2 of max(width,height).

annotationView.setView(customView);
annotationFromView.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
mapView.addAnnotation(annotationFromView, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
```